# pickerview is not responding to clicks at right side

Tags: iphone, uipickerview

i have a picker view which is in text field begin editing method not in viewdidload.if i click or scroll on right side, picker view for row method is not called.

```
    - (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
       viewForValueForPicker = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, txtvisitReason.frame.origin.y+txtvisitReason.frame.size.height, 180, 160)];
        UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 0, 180, 30)];
        toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
        UIBarButtonItem *btn = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(doneBtnPressToGetValue)]autorelease];
        [toolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:btn]];
        [viewForValueForPicker addSubview:toolBar];
                   pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
        pickerView.frame=CGRectMake(60, 30, 180, 140);
        pickerView.delegate=self;
        pickerView.dataSource=self;
        pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator=YES;
        [viewForValueForPicker addSubview:pickerView];
        [testscroll addSubview:viewForValueForPicker];

        [txtvisitReason resignFirstResponder];
        }
```

to know my problem i was implemented gesture recogniser method like this

```
   - (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
 {
if(touch.view==testscroll)//just checking my touch here
{

}
}
```

now if click on left side my touch is "table view cell content view "and on right side "uiscrollview"instead of "table view cell content view ".if iam scroling at that point my total view scrolls instead of picker view elements.
i am not getting any ideas.every where in my app its happening.plz give me an idea. thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, try correct your question be translation in at least translate.google.com and highlight methods you use by apostrophes to make it more understandable

Comment: @Ossir where iam going wrong with my pickerview

Comment: If you want to use picker view as input source the common practice is use `inputView` property(for `UIPickerView`) and `inputAccessoryView`(as toolbar for custom buttons) of `UITextField`. But if you want to use it other way you should provide more detailed question

Comment: i think you didn't get my question.my picker view for row is not calling some times.